# express vs secure websocket port clash?

Tags: node.js

I couldnt' find an exact similar post so i'm asking here.

I am trying to use the same port for my secure websocket (wss) and express app. however when i use A) app.listen() --> socket breaks B) when i use server.listen() => express breaks. I'm forced to do the listen twice with different ports. not ideal.

```
const app = express()
const server = https.createServer({ key, cert }, app);  
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server})

wss.on ...

server.listen(3002);
app.listen(3001);
```

I tried only keeping server.listen and the sockets work but express breaks. The vice versa also breaks the other. Is having dual port the only way to go? But it means my loadbalancer i have to split it.

I did not have this problem with normal ws. Only happening with secure websockets wss.

When i remove the app.listen it gives me an "xxx didn't send any data"
[image]

When i add it back (but on a different port) it works as expected.

The below is majority of my full code

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const fs = require('fs');

const https = require('https');
const express = require('express')
require('dotenv').config()
const keypath = process.env.environment=="production" ? process.env.key : 'localhost.key';
const certpath = process.env.environment=="production" ? process.env.cert : 'localhost.crt';
console.log("environment is ",process.env.environment)
const key = fs.readFileSync(keypath);
const cert = fs.readFileSync(certpath);
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const cors = require('cors')
const helmet = require('helmet')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const { MONGO_URI } = require('./config')
const worldRoutes = require('./src/routes/api/world_controller')
const environmentRoutes = require('./src/routes/api/environment_controller')
const worldObjectRoutes = require('./src/routes/api/worldObject_controller')
const interactionRoutes = require('./src/routes/api/interaction_controller')
const app = express()

app.use(helmet())
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())
app.use(morgan(':method :url :status :res[content-length] - :response-time ms'))
app.use(express.json())
mongoose
    .connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    })
    .then(() => console.log('MongoDB connected!'))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))

app.use('/api/world', worldRoutes)
app.use('/', baseRoutes)
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3002

const server = https.createServer({ key, cert }, app);  
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server})
wss.on('connection', (ws, req) => {
    console.log('received socket connection ', req.headers['sec-websocket-key'])
...
})


server.listen(3002);
app.listen(PORT);

  console.log('Server is listening on port ' + PORT);

//not sure if needed
// server.on('upgrade', (request, socket, head) => {
//     wss.handleUpgrade(request, socket, head, (socket) => {
//         wss.emit('connection', socket, request)
//     })
// })
```

Comment: You don't need `app.listen`, since you already have `server.listen` and `app` is the request handler of `server`. `app.listen` starts another HTTP web server (not HTTPS), and this clashes with the `server` you already have.

Comment: yes but when i remove app.listen, the server dosen't work (dosen't pick up the express calls, shows "didn't send any data"). I added a screenshot.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not appropriate to add SOLVED to the title or to add the solution you've found to the question. If you want to share that solution, do so by posting an answer in the space provided below for that purpose. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information. If you don't want to answer it yourself, then you can either leave it open and hope someone else does, or you can delete the question using the link below the tags at the lower left corner of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that i did not use a https:// in my call therefore it did not get picked up. Once i used the right https:// instead of http:// it was okay.